# Pass data to hook_preprocess_html from custom module

Tags: 7, theming

I'm trying to create a custom Drupal 7 module where it renders a custom page template. I want the data on /animals and /animals/getanimal to be in a custom HTML template.

After much searching and few successes, I've found that hook_preprocess_html works and that I can stop Drupal from loading the default template, but I'm struggling to pass data to my templates from the menu hook.

Is there a way to pass data from the menu hook to hook_preprocess_html, or is there another way where I can load my own custom template from the URLs in my custom module?

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu()
 * @return mixed
 */
function animal_farm_menu() {

  $items['animals'] = array(
    'title'           => 'Discover animals',
    'page callback'   => 'getDiscover',
    'page arguments'  => array(),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type'            => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    'menu_name'       => 'main-menu',
  );

  $items['animals/getanimal'] = array(
    'title'           => 'all animals',
    'page callback'   => 'getAnimal',
    'page arguments'  => array(),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type'            => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    'menu_name'       => 'main-menu',
  );

  return $items;
}


function getDiscover()
{
  $result = ['cat','dog','monkey','cow'];
  return $result;
}

function getAnimal()
{
  $result = ['cat','dog','monkey','cow'];
  return $result;
}


/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_html().
 */
function animal_farm_preprocess_html(&$vars) {

  $node = menu_get_object();

  $path = current_path();

  // echo $path;

  // Add a new theme suggestion when viewing node's of mynodetype.
  if ($path == 'animals') {
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'html__mynodetype';
    $vars['data'] = [1,2,4,'monkey'];
  }

  if ($path == 'animals/getanimal') {
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'animal_farm_discover';
    $vars['data'] = [1,2,4,'monkey'];
  }

}

/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function animal_farm_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  $theme = array();

  //Add our templates/html--mynodetype.tpl.php to the theme registry
  $theme['html__mynodetype'] = array(
    'template' => 'html--mynodetype',
    'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'animal_farm') . '/templates',
  );
  return $theme;
}
```

Comment: Why you are not using hook_preprocess_page for this as you are trying to alter page tpl. To pass data you can through hook_theme.

Comment: Please follow the below link for your query solution https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/theme-development/2013-04-19/simple-passing-data-from-module-to-template-through-theme

Comment: @prem I've tried that and it pulls in the base template, I don't want any template apart from my own custom one in the module.

Comment: @PremPatel I've tried the above solution too, but it too pulls in the base template, I don't want any template to come in to the module output.

Comment: Is there any specific reason, not to use html.tpl file? As it's only contain basic layout of page like head, and body tag with class.

Comment: I'm going to make the page embeddable on other sites, therefore I don't want the main sites theme coming through, I would like for the page to be blank with my own base template.

Comment: For that you just remove the theme css for this using hook CSS alter or page preprocessor hook and define your layout in your page custom template.

Comment: Thank you, but I need to have a stripped down HTML template, the base template contains too much code that isn't needed for this module.

Comment: That also you can remove based on your page menu condition. Just get the current menu link and include your content only other wise keep the normal content. Actually fully altering of html.tpl file is not recommended as it will impact SEO things.

Comment: Thank you, SEO isn't important because it will be embedded on other websites. My hope is that the module will have a base template file with html>body tags but with custom output based on the URL. I just need the module to render it's own html.tpl.php file and each menu hook can render its own content within that html.tpl.php file.

Comment: If you wanna just embedded you page and don't want page theme then it's better to use services module and create custom service api to get page data where you need to embed the page. And it will be fast as well compare to page embed.

Answer (score 0):

D7's [`html.tpl.php`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21html.tpl.php/7.x) doesn't contain menu in `$vars`, as it's supposed to represent the template that contains the high-level HTML document. This data is in [`page.tpl.php`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21page.tpl.php/7.x) via `$main_menu` / `$secondary_menu` vars.

If you need menu data in `hook_preprocess_html()` you can do something like call [`menu_tree_all_data('main-menu')`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/menu_tree_all_data/7.x) in your code which will retrieve the menu data for `main-menu`.